# The most minimalistic solar charge controller possible: will it work?

Tags: zener, lipo, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I want to build a solar panels device that can supply power to my doorbell, which is installed over a gate with no access to wires or power. The gate has a "bar" on top where I can install the panels, which would not have to "overflow" on the sides, for ahestetics reasons (meaning I'll have to build my own solar panel array to be linear).

As in winter I barely get any light, I also need to massively overshoot the voltage and power targets in order to allow harvesting energy while at the same time reducing parasitic currents to a minimum.
The voltage I need to overshoot as otherwise charging would not start. The power target I need to overshoot as exposure is not ideal and even if it was in December I would get only 1.5 sun-hours a day (if I'm lucky, not accounting for non-ideal exposure), meaning it's very difficult to charge anything.
Parasitic and passive currents I need to reduce to a minimum as I fully expect that for 3 months I won't be able to generate any power at all, so it's critical to avoid situations where the circuitry and solar panels drain the battery.

For this purpose I was thinking to connect in series several 5V, 30ma solar cells to get to a voltage of about 20V (30ma) which I would then need to reduce to charge a small LiPo button battery.
I was then thinking of using a Zener diode to limit the voltage across the solar panels array to 3.5V (along with a standard diode to prevent reverse-charge, of course), thus charging the LiPo battery below its maximum rated voltage and therefore eliminate overcharging problems.

Could this possibly work?
What mistakes am I making?
Any advice on what I could do instead?

Comment: It could work, but the zener would waste power and consume power from the batteries when panel does not provide enough. Also it must generate more power and be able to store it that what you use, and you don't say how much power you will use.

Comment: BTW, most wireless doorbells use *nanowatts* when off. One I use has two disposable U16 (AAA) cells, which last ~1 year. One could use a single Li-ion cell, partially charged to 3.5 V, and a *small* solar cell with 3.5 V limiter, to power it forever. Also, low-voltage (<6 V) Zener's do *not* have a sharp cutoff, and might be a continuous drain.

Comment: This 3.5V limiter of yours, would it be a Zener or would it be something else?

Comment: My limiter would be a Zener only. For the current I would rely on the scarce power of the panels and a resistor to avoid having an exceedingly high current for the battery.